# Generating complete SKUs in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Hi I have products that are made up of a couple of options. Each Option has a SKU Code. You can only select one option from each SKU Group and the options have to be concatenated in the order of the SKUGroup.

So for example i would have a list of options in a table in the DB that looked like

```
OptID   PID     SKU Price   SKUGroup

156727  93941   C   171.00  1
156728  93941   BN  171.00  1
156729  93941   PN  171.00  1
156718  93940   W   115.20  2
156719  93940   CA  115.20  2
156720  93940   BA  115.20  2
156721  93940   BNA 115.20  2
156722  93940   BN  115.20  2
156723  93940   BS  115.20  2
156716  93939   CHR 121.50  3
156717  93939   NK  138.00  3
```

And a few finished product SKUs would look something like:

```
C-W-CHR 407.70
C-W-NK  424.20
C-CA-CHR    407.20
C-CA-NK 424.20
```

I am trying to make a script that will create a listing of every possible combination of SKU and the price of the combined options.

I need this done in Classic ASP (vbscript) and I'm not that familiar with it. So I'm looking for all the help I can get.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would start by connecting to the database and creating three recordsets.

```
Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connection.Open ConnectionString 
Set rsOption1 = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
Set rsOption2 = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
Set rsOption3 = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rsOption1.Open "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE SKUGroup = 1", connection, 3,3
rsOption2.Open "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE SKUGroup = 2", connection, 3,3
rsOption3.Open "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE SKUGroup = 3", connection, 3,3
```

Then you can use nested loops to get the combinations.  Something like this (*Untested, this probably will not work as is, but it gives you an idea of how to do this*) (*Also this assumes that you have to select at least one option from each group*)

```
for i = 0 to rsOption1.RecordCount
    rsOption1.Move i, 1
    for j = 0 to rsOption2.RecordCount
        rsOption2.Move j, 1
        for k = 0 to rsOption3.RecordCount
            rsOption3.Move k, 1
            'Write rsOption1.Fields(2).Value & "-" & rsOption2.Fields(2).Value & _
            '"-" & rsOption3.Fields(2).Value & "     " & _
            'FormatCurrency((rsOption1.Fields(3).Value + rsOption2.Fields(3).Value + rsOption3.Fields(3).Value))
        Next
    Next
Next
```